# Rosjava install problem ./gradlew install

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to install ROSJava (Fuerte). I have already installed the regular ROS (Fuerte). I am working through the rosjava building steps (http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html).

When I get to ./gradlew install it shows a lot of Java errors:

Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:49)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:51)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)


I have installed the Oracle Java JDK, set JAVA_HOME with PATH="....:$JAVA_HOME/bin", Mercurial and Maven. 

Help!


---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43542/rosjava-install-problem-./gradlew-install/) by [LargeBearCat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3184/largebearcat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-09-10


Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gradle needs an internet connection.
Gradle tries to donwnload that file, but got a connection error. You can also try manually:

```
wget http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip
```

if that works, the gradle command should also work.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2